# Publishing stuck at waiting for Deployment state for 9.6

Tags: publishingfailed, sites-9.6, tridion-sites

We're trying to publish a page or component, Publishing is stuck at the Waiting for Deployment state

[image]

Any recommendation !!!

```
**Deployer Logs**
2023-03-16 11:14:06,699 WARN  [main] JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The connection to the host 172.31.14.12, named instance sqlexpress failed. Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.)
2023-03-16 11:14:55,487 ERROR [HeartbeatGenerator for Deployer] HeartbeatGenerator - Thread interrupted while running
2023-03-16 11:15:21,878 WARN  [main] JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The connection to the host 172.31.14.12, named instance sqlexpress failed. Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.)
2023-03-16 11:15:38,087 ERROR [pool(Queue Workers - ContentQueue)-5-thread-1] CommandQueuePoller - Could not process command: JSONCommand{verbs=[Content], action='TridionBootstrap', binaryIds=[tcm_0-10-66560.Content.zip], executionId='tcm:0-10-66560', properties={}}
com.sdl.delivery.deployer.api.processing.exception.ProcessingException: Can not create processing context - there are no pipelines available for command: JSONCommand{verbs=[Content], action='TridionBootstrap', binaryIds=[tcm_0-10-66560.Content.zip], executionId='tcm:0-10-66560', properties={}} and verbs: [Content]
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.BasicProcessingContextProvider.provideProcessingContext(BasicProcessingContextProvider.java:52)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.AkkaProcessingService.process(AkkaProcessingService.scala:31)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.worker.queue.impl.CommandQueuePoller.lambda$submitWork$1(CommandQueuePoller.java:144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

com.sdl.delivery.deployer.api.processing.exception.ProcessingException: Can not create processing context - there are no pipelines available for command: JSONCommand{verbs=[Content], action='TridionBootstrap', binaryIds=[tcm_0-XXXX-66560.Content.zip], executionId='tcm:0-XXXX-66560', properties={}} and verbs: [Content]
```

Comment: Can you please share the tridion version and also let us know if this is happening for all the pages or only for home page as i see on the screen shot . based on the logs , i see there could be a DB connection issue with the DB server and port , please make sure you are able to connect to the DB from the I also recommend to review the timeout settings https://gateway.sdl.com/articles/SolutionArticles/000003814

Comment: are you running this on your VM Instance or on your company network , if its on your VM instance , please go to deployer  logback.xml and change the log level to ERROR / DEBUG it will give you more information , i am sure its firewall issue blocking the DB port 1434, default SQL Port is 1433

Comment: Hi @AnandNS I am using Tridion site 9.6 version. It is happening for all the pages. Ports are configured in the firewall.

Comment: go to the deployer service under config look for logback.xml change the <property name="log.level" value="DEBUG"/> and clear the logs and restart the service publish the page again and under DEBUG will get more details might help troubleshoot the issue

Comment: Yes, it's helpful

Comment: did you get more details from the logs , do you still have publishing issue ??

Comment: Yes the issue is still there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144652/discussion-between-anand-n-s-and-sneh-gour).

Answer (score 0):

Configure a Server to Listen on a Specific TCP Port refer to [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port?view=sql-server-ver16) and update the windows firewall refer to this [link](https://docs.syskit.com/spdockit/troubleshooting/sql-server-connection/inbound-traffic)

As we  discussed the  cause of the below error is If Content Mashup is not intended to be used, use the deployer-sites or deployer-sites-combined role.

```
com.sdl.delivery.deployer.api.processing.exception.ProcessingException: Can not create processing context - there are no pipelines available for command: JSONCommand{verbs=[Content], action='TridionBootstrap', binaryIds=[tcm_0-XXXX-66560.Content.zip], executionId='tcm:0-XXXX-66560', properties={}} and verbs: [Content]
```

Please refer the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port?view=sql-server-ver16) for more details